# AWS billing alarm for EC2 usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing, aws-cost-explorer

I am trying to setup an alarm for my AWS Services (EC2 and S3 specifically). I want the alarm to be triggered when the estimated usage of my current month is 10% higher than the last month usage.

I've tried setting up alarm using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html but this only setup using the math expression.

Comment: Sorry, what's the question?

Comment: I am trying to setup alarm for service usage. but the alarm should only trigger if the present month's estimated usage is 10% more than last month's usage.